# How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Hadoop program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How I can get the name of the input file within a mapper? I have multiple input files stored in the input directory, each mapper may read a different file, and I need to know which file the mapper has read.

Answer (score 48):

First you need to get the input split, using the newer mapreduce API it would be done as follows:

```
context.getInputSplit();
```

But in order to get the file path and the file name you will need to first typecast the result into FileSplit.

So, in order to get the input file path you may do the following:

```
Path filePath = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath();
String filePathString = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
```

Similarly, to get the file name, you may just call upon getName(), like this:

```
String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
```

Comment: make sure you chose the right class to include (mapred vs mapreduce)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you figure this out?  The documentation of getInputSplit doesn't suggest that this is possible (at least to me...).

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore for multiple inputs, as the input split class returned is `TaggedInputSplit`, not `FileSplit`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502905/2599133 for a solution that works for `TaggedInputSplit` as well.

Answer (score 17):

Use this inside your mapper :

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

**Edit :**

Try this if you want to do it inside **configure()** through the **old API** :

```
String fileName = new String();
public void configure(JobConf job)
{
   filename = job.get("map.input.file");
}
```

Comment: I try to user ``context`` but does not have a method called ``getInputSplit``. Am I using old API?
Besides, can I do this things in the configure function instead of mapper?

Comment: With the latest hadoop 2.6.0 this does not work in mapreduce can you suggest on this.

Comment: In the end, I need to resort to some fiendish reflection hackery, it works! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130145/hadoop-multipleinputs-fails-with-classcastexception/11130420#11130420

Answer (score 15):

If you are using [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html), you can use the [JobConf variables in a streaming job's mapper/reducer.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#How+do+I+get+the+JobConf+variables+in+a+streaming+job%27s+mapper%2Freducer%3F)

As for the input file name of mapper, see the [Configured Parameters](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Configured+Parameters) section, the `map.input.file` variable (*the filename that the map is reading from*) is the one can get the jobs done. But note that:

> Note: During the execution of a streaming job, the names of the "mapred" parameters are transformed. The dots ( . ) become underscores ( _ ). For example, mapred.job.id becomes mapred_job_id and mapred.jar becomes mapred_jar. To get the values in a streaming job's mapper/reducer use the parameter names with the underscores.

---

For example, if you are using Python, then you can put this line in your mapper file:

```
import os
file_name = os.getenv('map_input_file')
print file_name
```

Comment: This worked locally, but in EMR using Yarn, I needed to use the suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915569/how-can-to-get-the-filename-from-a-streaming-mapreduce-job-in-r

Specifically: `os.getenv('mapreduce_map_input_file')`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the regular InputFormat, use this in your Mapper:

```
InputSplit is = context.getInputSplit();
Method method = is.getClass().getMethod("getInputSplit");
method.setAccessible(true);
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) method.invoke(is);
String currentFileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName()
```

If you're using CombineFileInputFormat, it's a different approach because it combines several small files into one relatively big file (depends on your configuration). Both the Mapper and RecordReader run on the same JVM so you can pass data between them when running.
You need to implement your own CombineFileRecordReaderWrapper and do as follows:

```
public class MyCombineFileRecordReaderWrapper<K, V> extends RecordReader<K, V>{
...
private static String mCurrentFilePath;
...
public void initialize(InputSplit combineSplit , TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        assert this.fileSplitIsValid(context);
        mCurrentFilePath = mFileSplit.getPath().toString();
        this.mDelegate.initialize(this.mFileSplit, context);
    }
...
public static String getCurrentFilePath() {
        return mCurrentFilePath;
    }
...
```

Then, in your Mapper, use this:

```
String currentFileName = MyCombineFileRecordReaderWrapper.getCurrentFilePath()
```

Hope I helped :-)

Answer (score 3):

Noticed on Hadoop 2.4 and greater using the **old** api this method produces a null value

```
String fileName = new String();
public void configure(JobConf job)
{
   fileName = job.get("map.input.file");
}
```

Alternatively you can utilize the Reporter object passed to your map function to get the InputSplit and cast to a FileSplit to retrieve the filename

```
public void map(LongWritable offset, Text record,
        OutputCollector<NullWritable, Text> out, Reporter rptr)
        throws IOException {

    FileSplit fsplit = (FileSplit) rptr.getInputSplit();
    String inputFileName = fsplit.getPath().getName();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first convert in to InputSplit by typecasting and then you need to type cast to FileSplit.

Example:

```
InputSplit inputSplit= (InputSplit)context.getInputSplit();
Path filePath = ((FileSplit) inputSplit).getPath();
String filePathString = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

```
String fileName = ((org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers which advocate casting to `FileSplit` will no longer work, as `FileSplit` instances are no longer returned for multiple inputs (so you will get a `ClassCastException`). Instead, `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TaggedInputSplit` instances are returned. Unfortunately, the `TaggedInputSplit` class is not accessible without using reflection. So here's a utility class I wrote for this. Just do:

```java
Path path = MapperUtils.getPath(context.getInputSplit());
```

in your `Mapper.setup(Context context)` method.

Here is the source code for my `MapperUtils` class:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Optional;

public class MapperUtils {

    public static Path getPath(InputSplit split) {
        return getFileSplit(split).map(FileSplit::getPath).orElseThrow(() -> 
            new AssertionError("cannot find path from split " + split.getClass()));
    }

    public static Optional<FileSplit> getFileSplit(InputSplit split) {
        if (split instanceof FileSplit) {
            return Optional.of((FileSplit)split);
        } else if (TaggedInputSplit.clazz.isInstance(split)) {
            return getFileSplit(TaggedInputSplit.getInputSplit(split));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private static final class TaggedInputSplit {
        private static final Class<?> clazz;
        private static final MethodHandle method;

        static {
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TaggedInputSplit");
                Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getInputSplit");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                method = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(m).asType(
                    MethodType.methodType(InputSplit.class, InputSplit.class));
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        static InputSplit getInputSplit(InputSplit o) {
            try {
                return (InputSplit) method.invokeExact(o);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private MapperUtils() { }

}
```

Comment: can you rewrite it using Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

For `org.apache.hadood.mapred` package the map function signature should be:

```
map(Object, Object, OutputCollector, Reporter)
```

So, to get the file name inside the map function, you could use the Reporter object like this:

```
String fileName = ((FileSplit) reporter.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MapperUtils {

    public static Path getPath(InputSplit split) {
        FileSplit fileSplit = getFileSplit(split);
        if (fileSplit == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("cannot find path from split " + split.getClass());
        } else {
            return fileSplit.getPath();
        }
    }

    public static FileSplit getFileSplit(InputSplit split) {
        if (split instanceof FileSplit) {
            return (FileSplit)split;
        } else if (TaggedInputSplit.clazz.isInstance(split)) {
            return getFileSplit(TaggedInputSplit.getInputSplit(split));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static final class TaggedInputSplit {
        private static final Class<?> clazz;
        private static final MethodHandle method;

        static {
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TaggedInputSplit");
                Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getInputSplit");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                method = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(m).asType(
                    MethodType.methodType(InputSplit.class, InputSplit.class));
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }

        static InputSplit getInputSplit(InputSplit o) {
            try {
                return (InputSplit) method.invokeExact(o);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private MapperUtils() { }

}
```

I rewrite the code hans-brende provides in Java 7, it worked.
But there is a problem that

File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
Bytes Read is zero if using MultipleInputs.

Answer (score -1):

With multiple inputs like this :

```
-Dwordcount.case.sensitive=false
hdfs://192.168.178.22:9000/user/hduser/inWiki
hdfs://192.168.178.22:9000/user/hduser/outWiki1
hdfs://192.168.178.22:9000/user/joe/wordcount/dict/dictionary.txt
-skip hdfs://192.168.178.22:9000/user/joe/wordcount/patterns.txt
```

For the file `dictionary.txt` I've written a procedure inside Map Code