# Mapreduce processing multiple files in same directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I have two files in my input folder, hadoop mapreduce will process both these files as . Is there a way to specify different processing for these two files? Suppose for example that instead of firing 1 for each word I [encounter](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html), I want to fire a 1 if this word was in file 1 and a 2 in the case it was seen in file 2 present in the same directory. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the file name as described in this post [How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Hadoop program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012482/how-to-get-the-input-file-name-in-the-mapper-in-a-hadoop-program])

Once you have the file name you can have a condition to check for the file name based on that you should be able to fire 1 or 2.