# Hadoop InputFormat set Key to Input File Path

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-crunch

My hadoop job needs to be aware of the input path that each record is derived from.

For example assume I am running a job over a collection of S3 objects:

```
s3://bucket/file1
s3://bucket/file2
s3://bucket/file3
```

I would like to reduce key value pairs such as

```
s3://bucket/file1    record1
s3://bucket/file1    record2
s3://bucket/file2    record1
...
```

Is there an extension of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` that would accomplish this? Or is there a better way to go about this than using a custom input format?

I know that in a mapper this information is accessible from the `MapContext` ([How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Hadoop program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012482/how-to-get-the-input-file-name-in-the-mapper-in-a-hadoop-program)) but I am using Apache Crunch and I cannot control whether any of my steps will be Maps or Reduces, however I can reliably control the InputFormat so it seemed to me to be the place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [my blog article to customize inputsplit and recordreader](https://my-bigdata-blog.blogspot.in/2017/07/hadoop-inputsplit-and-recordreader.html).

The code in that blog sets key as below (Line 69-70 of recordreader code)

```
value = new Text(line);
key = new LongWritable(splitstart);
```

In your case you need to set key as below, I didn't test it though.

```
key = fsplit.getPath().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I ended up writing my own as you describe. If someone is reading his ping me and ill dig up and post.