# How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Accumulo program?

Tags: accumulo

I am trying to the wordcount example and I wanted to print the name of the files where the word was found.  But I dont know as how to get the name of the input split in map function of accumulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command in the map function of your code:

context is the variable of the class Context defined in the arguments of your map function:

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

For more info: 
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012482/how-to-get-the-input-file-name-in-the-mapper-in-a-hadoop-program)