# Hadoop - Getting input paths, java api

Tags: hadoop, java

I am passing a file pattern:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/path/to/file*"));
```

And I wish to know which files actually matches it after the job finished running, provided that it was successful.

I have tried:

```
job.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir")
```

but it is returning the same thing:

```
"/path/to/file*"
```

I am wondering if there's a method to get the matching Paths without resorting to creating another routine to do the scanning of directories.

Your enlightenment is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link, it has a few ways to get the path in the mapper. But, I am sure its talking about a few more ways. :)

[How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Hadoop program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012482/how-to-get-the-input-file-name-in-the-mapper-in-a-hadoop-program)

Comment: Thanks, I did try out and check out the methods there before. I can get the input paths in mapper but not sure how to pass in back to main class. Having spent quite some time finding solution, I have resorted to the less graceful, aforementioned method. Thanks anyway.