# In a map reduce word count program need to fetch the files where the words exist

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I am reading multiple input files for a word count problem.

Example file names: 
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

I am able to get the word count but what should be added if I also want to get the file names along with count where the words exist.

for an example,

Contents of file 1: welcome to Hadoop

Contents of file 2: This is hadoop

Current output :

Hadoop 2

Is 1

This 1

To 1

Welcome 1

Expected output:

Hadoop 2 File01.txt File02.txt

Is 1 File02.txt

This 1 File02.txt

To 1 File01.txt

Welcome 1 File01.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the input file name in the mapper in a Hadoop program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012482/how-to-get-the-input-file-name-in-the-mapper-in-a-hadoop-program)

Comment: Thanks @BenWatson

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st do a input a split
`String file = ((FileSplit)inputSplit).getPath().getName();`
and collect word and filename from mapper as output.

In the reducer count the file name against the key and increment the counter and keep appending the file name.

```
   file += filename;
   textString = counter + file;
   output.collect(key,new Text(textString));
```

This solved the problem.