# Not able to cast from TaggedInputSplit to FileSplit in MR 2.3

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am getting this classcast exception when I am using MultipleInput in my MR job.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TaggedInputSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit
    at com.capitalone.integratekeys.mapreduce.mapper.IntegrationKeysMapperInput.setup(IntegrationKeysMapperInput.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

inputSource = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
```

Although I found a ticket in JIRA about it saying its solved.But I am still facing this issue. Please give me some inputs.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130145/hadoop-multipleinputs-fails-with-classcastexception

Comment: I have already seen that question. It was asked long time back. This is a bug actually and is acclaimed to be fixed in hadoop 0.20.1 version. But I am still facing this issue. So wanted to know whether someone is facing this issue.

Comment: Which JIRA? I see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2226 is unresolved. Have you tried the accepted answer in the question linked above?

Comment: hope this helps... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1178

Comment: I have tried that. But I don't wanna use reflection as its not good for optimization purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

inputSource = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();

context.getInputSplit() is instance of TaggedInputSplit

And convert to FileSplit.

I check both class have not parent child relation.
So get exception.
You can use Hadoop conf for get inputSource.

Way to get input source:
JobContext context in argument

inputSource=context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir", null);

If you not able to get input source, Please provide me how to set input file path in driver program

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know.

Comment: replace this line inputSource = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString(); with inputSource=context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir", null);

Comment: But this gives us an empty string but does not throw any error,, Please help me with this