# Parsing XML using DOM Parser

Tags: java, dom

I am using DOM parser to parse an XML. The xml format is :

```
<PriceList>
        <PriceTag>
            <Pricing priceCode = "EATIN">
                <Price></Price>
                <Tax
                    taxCode = "ALWAYS"
                    rule = "TAX_CHAIN"
                    entry = "4"/>
            </Pricing>
            <Pricing priceCode = "TAKEOUT">
                <Price></Price>
                <Tax
                    taxCode = "ALWAYS"
                    rule = "TAX_CHAIN"
                    entry = "4"/>
            </Pricing>
            <Pricing priceCode = "OTHER">
                <Price></Price>
                <Tax
                    taxCode = "ALWAYS"
                    rule = "TAX_CHAIN"
                    entry = "4"/>
            </Pricing>
        </PriceTag>
    </PriceList>
```

If the priceCode = "EATIN", I want to read the price.

Can any one help me to implement this.

Comment: Have you checked this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130145/hadoop-multipleinputs-fails-with-classcastexception

Comment: yes, I tried this, but still I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line 
`fileName  = ((FileSplit)context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();` with     `fileName = context.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inpu‌​tdir", null);`